# checking empty resultset

Tags: java, jsp

i'm founding a solution of checking the empty resultset... here is the code

```
     temp = rs1;
     boolean hasRows = temp.next();


     if (hasRows) {  
        while (rs1.next()) {
            String pid = rs1.getString("pid");
            System.out.println(pid);
            String pd = rs1.getString("description");
            double price = rs1.getDouble("price");%>
                    <br>
                    Product id : <%=pid %><br>
                    Description : <%=pd %><br>
                    Price : <%=price %>
      <%
                }
          }
```

it seems that `temp.next()` will affect rs.next(), the result can't be printed out finally. Why?

Comment: This is object-oriented. `temp` refers to the same `ResultSet` instance as `rs`...

Comment: @home This has nothing to do with object-orientation, it's just that `temp` and `rs1` reference the same object. To OP, use `while (rs1.hasNext()) { ... }`.

Comment: @Kristian Antonsen: It is not necessarily related to OO, but as you mentioned as well it refers to an object and I'd call pointers or references a common OO principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next()` method already checks the control that you try. If result set `rs1` has elements the loop will be entered.
You don't seem to use `temp` anywhere. Why? Abandon it and get your job done, try this:

```
      boolean loopEntered = false;
      while (rs1.next())
      {
                loopEntered = true;
                String pid = rs1.getString("pid");
                System.out.println(pid);
                String pd = rs1.getString("description");
                double price = rs1.getDouble("price");

              %>
                 <br>
                 Product id : <%=pid %><br>
                 Description : <%=pd %><br>
                 Price : <%=price %>
              <%
      }

      if(!loopEntered)
      // print your error messages.
```

Comment: but how to print a "product not found" if the resultset is empty?

Comment: There is no `hasNext()` method for `ResultSets`. Instead, you can set a flag inside the while loop. Or you keep `if (rs1.next())` and change the `while` loop to a `do ... while`.

Comment: @TPete so simply checking its emptiness just after the loop will work. I changed the code.

Comment: @deporter rs == rs1?with your code as above currently, if there are data found, the data will be printed and lastly the errors will be printed.

Comment: @tanyehzheng sorry for typo, rs=rs1. the things that you say are mutually exclusive. if the data is printed then "not found" errors cannot be printed.  think carefully.

Comment: @deporter The 'while' statement will loop until rs1.next() returns false, all subsequent calls to rs1.next() will return false. "if(!rs1.next())" will be true and make the error message got printed. Isn't it?

Comment: @tanyehzheng now it is OK i guess.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do like this

```
if(rs.next()){
    do {                
        //print product details
    } while (rs.next());
}else{
    //print product not found
}
```